# Строка это динамическая структура данных ? Задача на Питонтьютор

Tags: python

попалась задача на [питонтьюторе](http://pythontutor.ru/lessons/functions/problems/reverse_rec/) :

> Дана последовательность целых чисел, заканчивающаяся числом 0.
> Выведите эту последовательность в обратном порядке.При решении этой
> задачи нельзя пользоваться массивами и прочими динамическими
> структурами данных.Рекурсия вам поможет.

Я не до конца могу понять условие про динамическую структуру данных , понимаю что к ним относится массив ,кортеж , список , но относится ли к ним строка ? (хочу записывать промежуточные данные в строку , потом выводить ее оттуда же)

P.S. прошу не давайте мне конечного решения , если хотите помочь , подтолкните в эту сторону , спасибо :)

Comment: Вам просто надо выводить числа в порядке выхода из рекурсии: ввод числа и если нуль, то вывод и выход иначе ещё один вызов функции после чего идет вывод введенного ранее числа. Как-то так.

Comment: так как в задаче вывод последовательный и через `print`, то без рекурсии задача тоже решается, с помощью `while` и `pop()`

Comment: @SergFSM а к чему вы будете `pop` применять, если нельзя использовать динамические структуры ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs, ну так сказано же "_Дана последовательность целых чисел_". Хотя для меня это условие тоже не очевидно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массив и списки в Python это синонимы.

Кортеж не относится к динамическим, т.к. мы не можем производить манипуляции по добавлению/изменению/удалению элементов.

Строка тоже является динамической. Вот пример изменения

```
myVar = 'строк'
myVar += 'a'

print(myVar) # выдаст "строка"
```

В данной задаче вам необходимо использовать кортежи.